# Select data where Datetime is less than 30 days Cosmos Db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to select data with a date less than 30 days in Cosmos Db but I get an error with my query. Here is my query:

`SELECT * FROM c where c.Field = 'value' AND DATEDIFF(DAY, c.TimeStamp, GETDATE()) = 30`

Comment: What type is your date field is?

Comment: If you want all dates less than 30 days old shouldn't it be `DATEDIFF(DAY, c.TimeStamp, GETDATE()) < 30` ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: This is the error I am getting
Failed to query item for container DatabaseName-Main: {"code":400,"body":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":55,\"end\":58},\"code\":\"SC2001\",\"message\":\"Identifier 'DAY' could not be resolved.\"},{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":73,\"end\":80},\"code\":\"SC2005\",\"message\":\"'GETDATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.\"},{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":46,\"end\":54},\"code\":\"

Comment: @FernandoZamperin, it's a string field that represents the code in my table

Answer (score 1):

If you refer the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates#storing-datetimes)

> you can store DateTimes as Unix timestamps, that is, as a number
>   representing the number of elapsed seconds since January 1, 1970.
>   Azure Cosmos DB's internal Timestamp (_ts) property follows this
>   approach. You can use the UnixDateTimeConverter class to serialize
>   DateTimes as numbers.

I would suggest you to serialize DateTimes as numbers to compare with the conditions. You can certainly use a User Defined Function to convert as

UDF:

```
function convertToDate(datetime){
    datetime = datetime.replace(/-/g,'/')  
    if(datetime){
        var date = new Date(datetime);
    }else{
        var date = new Date();
    }
    opDate = date.getTime(); 
    return opDate;
}
```

you can write a query to compare the dates and get it

```
SELECT c.LogDate FROM c
where udf.convertTime(c.TimeStamp) > udf.convertTime('2019-09-05') 
and udf.convertTime(c.TimeStamp) < udf.convertTime('2019-10-05')
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM c where c.Field = 'value' AND DATEDIFF("day", startdate, enddate) < 30